# Es6: How to pass this when i use callbacks?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

I have the following example:

```
import express from 'express';
class myController{
  constructor(){
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.router.get('/', this.getData);
  }
  
  getData(){
    console.log(this); //error
  }
}
```

**What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: did you try this.router.get('/', this.getData.bind(this)); ? as `getData` is used as a callback I think the context is not the one you expect when the callback is called, so you need to use the **bind** function to preserve the value of this

Comment: See also: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)